# On Application Resume From Background To Foreground, App Restarts From First Navigation Screen

Tags: ios, react-native

I have following navigation stack

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    AppSplashScreen: AppSplashScreen,
    LanguageScreen: LanguageScreen,
    WalkthroughScreen: WalkthroughScreen,
    LoginScreen: LoginScreen,
    ForgotPasswordScreen: ForgotPasswordScreen,
    ResetPasswordScreen: ResetPasswordScreen,
    RegistrationTypeScreen: RegistrationTypeScreen,
    RegistrationFormScreen: RegistrationFormScreen,
    OTPConfirmationScreen: OTPConfirmationScreen,
    BottomTabNavigator: BottomTabNavigator
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#000000' },
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default App;
```

I am displaying splash screen video when the first app opens.

Here is what my `AppSplashScreen` looks like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import Video from 'react-native-video';
import { VIDEO_SPLASH_2 } from '../assets/videos/index';

export default class AppSplashScreen extends Component {

    state = {
        displayVideoPlayer: true,
        firstLaunch: false
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        SplashScreen.hide();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.setState({
            displayVideoPlayer: false
        });
    }

    isFirstLaunch() {
        let firstLaunch = true;
        if (true === storage.get('APP_ALREADY_LAUNCHED')) {
            firstLaunch = false;
        } else {
            storage.set('APP_ALREADY_LAUNCHED', true);
            firstLaunch = true;
        }
        return firstLaunch;
    }

    didCompleteVideoPlayback() {
        if (true === this.state.displayVideoPlayer) {
            this.setState({
                displayVideoPlayer: false
            });
        }
        const currentRouteName = this.props.navigation.state.routeName;
        if ('AppSplashScreen' !== currentRouteName) {
            return false;
        }
        if (true === global.SKIP_SPLASH_SCREEN_REDIRECT) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.isFirstLaunch()) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('LanguageScreen');
            return false;
        }
        this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#000000', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                {true === this.state.displayVideoPlayer &&
                    <Video
                        source={VIDEO_SPLASH_2}
                        muted={true}
                        repeat={false}
                        playInBackground={false}
                        resizeMode="contain"
                        onEnd={() => this.didCompleteVideoPlayback()}
                        style={{height: '100%', width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#000000'}}
                    />
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

My issue is, whenever I put the application in Background, and resume after 30 seconds, it always starts with `AppSplashScreen` whereas I expect it to resume from the last screen. It works correctly if I open it before 30 seconds. I assume somewhere it is killing the memory and starting the app from start when I resume after 30 second.

What could be the issue here. Or is there another workaround to resume the app in the same screen where the user left off.

Comment: if I recall, it's an iOS13 bug.

Comment: Is there any reference to confirm?

Comment: https://techcrunch.com/2019/11/07/ios-13-2-2-fixes-bug-that-kills-your-background-apps-prematurely-whats-new/ and many other similar articles you can find for yourself.

Comment: One more thing, have you tried `encodeRestorableState(with:)` and `decodeRestorableStatez(with:)`? I don't know about your app, but in my case it helped.

Comment: Thank you Maysam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using `State Persistence` of react-navigation

Here is the documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/state-persistence/

Here is what my App.js look like now

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {

    const persistenceKey = "navigationStatePersistenceKey"
    const persistNavigationState = async (navState) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(persistenceKey, JSON.stringify(navState));
        } catch(err) {
            // handle error
        }
    }
    const loadNavigationState = async () => {
        const jsonString = await AsyncStorage.getItem(persistenceKey);
        return JSON.parse(jsonString);
    }
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#000000'}}>
            <AppContainer
                persistNavigationState={persistNavigationState}
                loadNavigationState={loadNavigationState}
            />
        </View>
    );
};
```

It now takes user to the same screen where it was left off, no more restart from first screen.